# Using shell vs python for parallelism

Tags: python, multithreading, shell

Let's say I have many tasks N to run  (~thousands) and each task takes a good amount of time X (few minutes to hours). Luckily, each of these tasks can be run independently. Each task is a shell command invoked through Python.

**Edit**: Each task is almost identical, so I don't really need to abstract tasks.

Which is better? (in terms of memory required, cpu usage, background task limits ...)

1. Invoke each task as a background process in a single threaded python script (use files/redirection for tracking) or,
2. Multiple python threads, each one calling the shell command.

I need python here primarily to interact with db, do some logic, read files etc.

Is this a tradeoff worth considering or either way is fine?

Ideally it would be nice if there are some statistics/graphs around the two approaches for different N/X values.

PS: Google and SO search didn't give me any leads. I am sorry if there is something like this already.

Thanks!

Comment: you could try celery http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: You can try it very simply indeed with **GNU Parallel** - even spreading it across multiple machines.

Comment: Thanks @Jacky. Celery looks like an overkill to me because of two reasons- firstly I don't really need a task abstraction because all my tasks are identical, and secondly it is not a distributed system i.e they are fired on a single box (which is more like a gateway).